# Space between footnote marks and the text of the footnotes

Tags: spacing, footnotes

I am new with LaTex and I would like to be able to reproduce the format I usually use for the footnotes (with MS Word or OpenOffice) in LaTeX. My footnotes look like in the following example:
[image: example of footnotes style]

To obtain this result, I usually to do so I set up the indents like this: [image: indents] and then I add a tabular space (note sure that is it the correct name of it actually) between the footnote mark and the text of the footnote, like this:[image: tab]. Would it be possible to obtain the same result with LaTeX and how?

For now I use the `biblatex` package but I have nothing specified about the formatting of the footnotes.

I tried to find my question here but I am not a native speaker and may be I use an incorrect vocabulary preventing me from finding it.

Here my document (an example), I am using the BOOK class as it is for the writing of my PhD thesis but I am also open to change it for another one. I am now trying LaTeX more than really using it to see if it is suitable for me (I am a lawyer so I don't have specifically need of it, but in the same time I find it much more powerful than the other way I tried).

```
\documentclass[a4paper, twoside, 12pt]{book}

\usepackage[style=oscola]{biblatex}
\usepackage[style=british]{csquotes}
\addbibresource{Bibliography/Bibliography.bib}



\begin{document}

here the text \footnote{here the text of the footnote}

\end{document}
```

Thank you very much in advance for your answers and help.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Can you prepare a [MWE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228/35864) of what your document and the footnotes look like now? In particular we need to know the documentclass you plan on using and any packages that might modify footnote behaviour. (`biblatex` should have no bearing on any of this whatsoever.)

Comment: Have a look at the footmisc package (https://www.ctan.org/pkg/footmisc)

Comment: I edited my question to integrate it. Thank you very much for your comments. I didn't know if biblatex was relevant so I preferred to mention it.

Answer (score 1):

Many people no longer use the classes that ship with LaTeX itself, but the KOMA-script classes. They provide among a lot of other useful stuff high level commands. You can determine the layout of your document by a small number of commands. Let's have it:

```
\documentclass[papersize]{scrartcl}
\deffootnote{1.5em}{1em}{%
  \makebox[1.5em][l]{\thefootnotemark}}

\usepackage{blindtext}
\begin{document}

In the beginning\footnote{\blindtext} was darkness\footnote{Well,
  probably, nobody was there and we only can guess.}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you, it works with your document class, not with LaTeX's document class book. I didn't know before the KOMA-script classes, I will have a look to it.

Comment: @François Well, KOMA-script is nothing to comprehend in a short glance. There is an english and a german manual. At least read section 3. And recently there have been some important improvements, so if you miss something, which is not documented in the manual, and has not already been explained here, just ask.

Answer (score 0):

The footmisc package, suggested by Rüdiger Voigt, works actually perfectly:

```
\usepackage[hang]{footmisc}
```

Thank you for all your answers and help!

Comment: Please don't use answers in order to express `Thank you`.