# Horizontal spacing between the footnote mark and the footnote text

Tags: spacing, footnotes

Using pdfLaTeX, typesetting a `\documentclass[11pt]{article}`, and looking at the clip below as an example, I would like to increase the horizontal spacing between the footnote mark ("2") and the footnote text ("This sentence"). This results from a plain `text in the body\footnote{This sentence}`:

[image]

I would like to have this for all footnotes.
And I am not interested in making the whole body of the footnote hang at an indentation as `\usepackage[hang]{footmisc}` [can do](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/230895/89275).

I found information on how to tweak the space between the calling text and the footnote mark in the body of the text, but missed tips on the similar action down in the footnote area.

Comment: What document class are you using? Because the answer can depend on the documentclass.

Comment: @cktai  `\documentclass[11pt]{article}`, added to the question, thanks for pointing this out

Comment: `scrartcl` also puts number and text _very_ close together.